# Null Pointer when invoking getRequestContext on APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent - AWS Lambda (Java)

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

Relatively new to Java and I'm just trying to print out the contents of my request context. Not sure how to get past this null pointer exception. This is thrown while building, not on runtime. Which confuses me even more. Anyway, here's my code. It's just a boiler plate SAM Lambda handler function with **println** statement I added. Would appreciate any help on this!

```
public class App implements RequestHandler<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent> {

public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(final APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent input, final Context context) {
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers.put("X-Custom-Header", "application/json");

    APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent response = new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent()
            .withHeaders(headers);

    try {

        System.out.println("*** REQUEST CONTEXT ***");
        System.out.println(input.getRequestContext());

        final String pageContents = this.getPageContents("https://checkip.amazonaws.com");
        String output = String.format("{ \"message\": \"Hello There!\", \"location\": \"%s\" }", pageContents);

        return response
                .withStatusCode(200)
                .withBody(output);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return response
                .withBody("{}")
                .withStatusCode(500);
    }
}

private String getPageContents(String address) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(address);
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()))) {
        return br.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
    }
}
```

}

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent.getRequestContext()" because "input" is null
```